# Length in bytes for CSRF token

Tags: php, token, csrf

I was researching about CSRF prevention, specifically the unpredictable token, a random alphanumerical string. I found that one of the best solutions to generate the token is:

```
$token = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bytes));
```

Some people says that 16 bytes is enough for the length parameter. ($bytes = 16)
Others say that 32 bytes is the right option. ($bytes = 32)

However, [in this page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_CSRF_Guard), OWASP recommends a 512 bits random string. To achieve this number, I would have to pass 64 as the length parameter. ($bytes = 64)
But I read too that, as this length gets bigger, it can seriously reduce performance.

So I don't have an idea of wich length I should use. What is the best option? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider a 128 bits of entropy in a token to be the de-facto standard. OWASP and CWE both recommend this as a minimum.

Comment: I'm new to web development. Now I have an idea of what is entropy. But what do you mean exactly by "128 bits of entropy"? Does it mean a 128 bits random string? If it does, I only need to pass 16 bytes as the parameter length in that function, right?

Comment: This answer would be much improved if it includes links to official references.